# Searching within Python files using Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I have a mixed Javascript+Python project that I'm developing using Webstorm 6. Many times I want to find some string using 'Find in Path' functionality, but it seems to ignore the contents of Python files, finding everything just fine in js and html ones.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. Is .py extension associated with any file type in Settings/File Types? Files with 'unknown' extensions might be skipped on searching. Please see [this thread](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5261051) for more info